# Laravel/Guzzle Issue

Tags: php, laravel-5, cpanel, guzzle, whm

Hello guys i have an issue when trying to use guzzle in laravel and i have spent ages trying to google it and research what the problem could be. This is a very simple get request for WHM/Cpanel api

```
$client = new Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://delta.cloudns.io:2087/json-api/accountsummary…', [
'auth' => [ 'username','passowrd']
]);
```

Now i get a 200 status for the request but i am not getting any data back and in the network tab on firefox/chrome tools the page is showing as a error 500.

The code above i put into the index of my controller. I have tested the username and password and url in postman and it works correctly and i get back the data i expect.

Any help would greatly appreciated. Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: The typo in `passowrd` has nothing to do with it has it?

Comment: Thanks :) but no i just removed my username and password and mistyped password lol

Answer (score 0):

Someone helped point me in the right direction. I should have been using $res->getBody()->getContents(); to get the data returned.